# Virtualenv starting file from terminal - cant use file i started

Tags: python, terminal, switching

Dears,

I learned today how to use virtualenv for my python projects. Now I started my pygame file from virtualenv via terminal "python mygame.py" and it worked, however I cannot play the actual game. When I move to the pygame window and hit any key, the output continues being displayed in the terminal. How can I switch to the actual pygame window and play the game while I am in the virtualenv?

Thank you

Comment: We need more information. Tell us step by step what you're doing. What operating system and Python version do you use? And what is the desired behavior of the game? I guess it would help if we could see and run your code ([a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: The code does run very well if I start it from my global python installation. However if I use "source virtualenv snake/bin/activate" and then "python snake.py" I does start as well, however when try to click anything in the window or hit any keys, they are being called in the terminal, not the game window.

Comment: OK, I resolved the issue with Pycharm editor. I created a new virtual env with Python 3.6 and installed pygame and it worked. However I still dont know why I was not able to play the game when I started it via terminal in the venv - but it is not important now anymore.